# How can I make an activity on be openable when launched?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app where my LAUNCHER activity, named dispatch activity, which sees whether the user has logged in before or not(in `onCreate()`), and then launches the correct activity. And when the correct activity is launched, I can tap the back button on my device and it goes back to the dispatch activity, and it stays there until the user refreshes the app. I only want the activity open-able by LAUNCHER. So if the user clicks the back button on the device, it stays there, like the dispatch activity doesn't exist. (By the back button I mean by that icon next to the home button on the tablet)

Hope you can help

Comment: finish() your dispatch activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this : when you start the `second activity`, at the same time you exit (run `finish()`) on your `dispatch activity`?

**EDIT**: like this: (in your Dispatch Activity)

```
//quit your Dispatch Activity
finish();

//start new activity
startActivity(new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class));
```

Comment: Do I just type in `finish()` after launching the activity?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to play with intent flags. In this particular case, have a look at 
[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).

Set it for your dispatch activity right in the manifest and it won't be kept in the history stack.

Answer (score 0):

Add LAUNCHER activity as a FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.

Just define in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="LAUNCHER ACTIVITY"
    android:noHistory="true"
    ...
></activity>
```

Now validate your user login stuff and just start your next activity. Rest of the stuff will be taken care by Android.